# Reflect.getMetadata error in unit test with jest while dealing to redis

Tags: typescript, ts-jest, ioredis

```
Test suite failed to run

 TypeError: Reflect.getMetadata is not a function
      at Object.resolveToTypeWrapper (node_modules/src/utils/resolve-to-type-wrapper.util.ts:51:62)
      at node_modules/src/decorators/inject.decorator.ts:19:25
      at src/Service/AcquirerService.ts:2373:5
      at Object.<anonymous>.__decorate (src/Service/AcquirerService.ts:2299:38)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Service/AcquirerService.ts:6:37)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/Service/CacheService.ts:3:1)
```

In my file, one import is for `cacheService` in which I try to delete a token. I used the `del` method on Redis cache, but it throws the above error.